# Filtro com chekbox mysql php

Tags: php, checkbox, filtro

Poderia me ajudar como eu faria a concatenação de strings nessa pesquisa, passando qual a tabela certa se seria a i ou c?

```
select i.nome from imovel i join cidade c
where c.nome in ("Campo Grande","Paranaíba")
and i.tipo in ("Casa","Apartamento")
and i.dormitorio in ("4","5")

function parseMysqlQuery($array) {

    $output = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $output .= !$output ? " WHERE $table.$key " : " AND $table.$key";
        $output .= ' IN ("' . implode('","', $value) . '")';
    }
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
    return $output;
}

$array = (array)filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,
        array( 'num' =>
                 array( 'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                        'flags' => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY),
                        'grupo'  => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
                        ),
                        'dt_de_inducao' => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
                        ),
                )
        );

//SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'folha_tarefa' if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { $array = array_filter($array);

$in = parseMysqlQuery($array);

$query = "SELECT * FROM contratos " . $in;.
```

Esse é um filtro com checkbox, só que eu tenho uma pesquisa que faço um join left e nao estou conseguindo fazer com que meu php ele entenda em qual table deve pesquisar, ex nometable.nomecoluna

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico na sua questão?

Comment: Por que [abriu duas perguntas relativas do mesmo assunto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143876/filtro-php-chebox), sendo uma delas mais incompleta?

Comment: poxa estou apredendo a usar o site e nao tinha visto o botão de edição, por isso que abri 2

Comment: Você precisa realmente adotar esse método mal escrito? Uma observação, "concatenização" não existe, o correto é "concatenação". 
Pelo que parece `$table.$key` seria `nome_tabela.campo` e `$value` o valor da tabela, então o correto seria passar uma estrutura de array que tivessem cada um desses parâmetros. Sendo que `$table`, não faz parte da função, mas uma variável externa. `$array = array(array('campo'=>'valor'),array('campo'=>'valor'), ...);`

Comment: Obrigado pela correção Ivan Ferrer, já corrigi. bem eu preciso fazer um filtro e fazendo uma pesquisa achei esse método, (eu sou nova em programação php), comecei a estudar esse código e me deparei com esse problema de como colocar o nome da tabela concatenado com o campo, se você tiver algum link de estudo sobre o assunto de filtros para que eu possa estudar agradeço, vou tentar usar essa forma que você escreveu pra mim.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que parece `$table.$key` seria `nome_tabela.campo` e `$value` o valor da tabela, então o correto seria passar uma estrutura de array similar a este formato:

```
$table = 'imovel';

$arrIn = array(
           array('c.nome'=> array('Campo Grande','Paranaíba')),
           array('i.tipo'=> array('Casa','Apartamento')),
           array('i.dormitorio'=> array('4','5'))
        );
$in = parseMysqlQuery($arrIn);

$query = "select i.nome from {$table} i join cidade c on(c.id_cidade=i.id_fk_cidade)
where c.nome " . $in;
```