# Filtro php chebox

Tags: php, checkbox, filtro

```
function parseMysqlQuery($array) {

$output = ''; foreach( $array as $key => $value){

   $output .= !$output ? " WHERE $table.$key " : " AND $table.$key";
   $output .= ' IN ("' . implode('","', $value) . '")';
}
echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
return $output;
}

$array = (array)filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array( "num" => array( 'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY, ),

'grupo' => array(
    'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
),

'dt_de_inducao' => array(
    'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
),
));

//SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'folha_tarefa' if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { $array = array_filter($array);

$in = parseMysqlQuery($array);

$query = "SELECT * FROM contratos " . $in;
```

Esse é um filtro com checkbox, só que eu tenho uma pesquisa que faço um join left e nao estou conseguindo fazer com que meu php ele entenda em qual table deve pesquisar, ex nometable.nomecoluna

Comment: Por que [abriu duas perguntas relativas do mesmo assunto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143854/filtro-com-chekbox-mysql-php), sendo que esta do link está mais completa?